# How to convert LocalTime to String to add it to an array

Tags: java, arrays, java-time

I want to add the current time to an array of strings but

`LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT"));`

provides the type LocalTime and the required type is a string. How can I convert Localtime into String?

Comment: Use `LocalTime#toString()`...? If you need it in a different format then use `DateTimeFormatter`. But the better option is to store the `LocalTime` itself.

Comment: It's not clear to me what this has to do with the title of your question. Please edit appropriately so that the title and body of the question are consistent.

Comment: Why not try the LocalTime.toString() or LocalTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)?

Comment: You don’t want to add your times as strings to your array (except if you need it for an API that requires a string array). Make yourself a `LocalTime[]`, an array of `LocalTime` objects. You can always format each later if you need it for presentation or for interchange with another system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the default format, you can simply use `LocalTime#toString`. However, if you need the string in a custom format, you will have to use `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        // An String [] of size 3
        String[] arr = new String[3];

        // Add the string representation in default format
        arr[0] = now.toString();

        // Add the string representation in a custom format
        arr[1] = now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[15:50:10.106099, 03:50:10 PM, null]
```

Comment: did it by using `LocalTime[]` as my array as mentioned above but ty for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use toString() method of LocalTime, or format() method
Check more in here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalTime

Comment: Ok thanks. How do I use it? LocalTime.parse("GMT").toString();;   works but where is it saved and how do I access it?

Comment: @xiaofeng That question indicates a lack of fundamental knowledge. If you truly don't understand how `LocalTime#toString()`, object references, and arrays work then I suggest (re)visiting tutorials, videos, books, and other sources covering the basics of Java. This comment is not meant to belittle you nor your efforts, but it's important to understand the basics before moving on to more complex ideas.

Comment: thought it doesnt matter because the question is a duplicate